# php class extended multiple times

Tags: php, connection, pdo, extend

After spending half an hour to find a proper, self-explaining title for this question, I finally gave up. Apologies for it, I'm not a native English speaker.

Anyways, the question is about using a particular class to be extended multiple times - not multiple inheritance. So, imagine two repository classes called from the same function:

```
public function someFunction() 
{
   $qp = QuestionRepository();
   $cp = CommentRepository();
}
```

and the QuestionRepository is like:

```
class QuestionRepository extends PDO 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

the CommentRepository is like:

```
class CommentRepository extends PDO 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

whereas the PDO class is like this:

```
class PDO 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $pdo = new PDO(...);
    } 
}
```

So basically, the `PDO` class is extended twice, therefore two instances of PDO is initiated. However, the question is whether this means 2 different connections to mysql - which would result in performance decrease or the pdo recognizes that there is an alive connection therefore it just ignores the second instance?

Comment: Are you familiar with [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) and the [singleton pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton)?

Comment: not really, I'm still learning. I'll give it a check

Comment: See my edited comment. The singleton pattern combined with `static` is probably especially useful here.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yep I was trying to implement it :) Thanks for the advice.

Comment: btw, your English is pretty damned good :)

Comment: @Hamish haha thanks. I guess finally being a political science major helped me a bit since I'm doing really heavy readings in English :D But still, that doesn't change the fact that I'm not native :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a "static" field in PDO for the mysql connection. That way the same field will be used in each instance, regardless of which subclass is responsible for the instantiation.

It also requires that you access the field statically; `PDO::$mysql_link;`

If you declare the field without specifying visibility it will be public, meaning you'll be able to refer to the same field from anywhere as long as PDO is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a check from PDO.

But you have different choices. Build a Singelton PDO Object and use this Singleton in each of your classes or use dependecy injection. Meaning setup one PDO Object  and inject it to your class in the constructor (constructor injection) or with another function (setter injection)

I would run with dependency injection, so you can easily change your "database access object"

Comment: that's actually the way I was doing before, but I was not comfortable with that :) Thanks though

Comment: Trust me, don't solve this with inheritance. You will regret that sooner or later. Use dependency injection or a singleton.

Comment: At a first view it looks not very natural using dependency injection, because the code feels weird. You think you are misusing somewhat. I know what you feel :) To make the code more beautiful, build a factory around it, and hide the injection from your eyes :)

Comment: AH sorry, didn't see you were suggesting the singleton. That's the way I'm trying now :)